# Problems with JQuery conflicts in VM

Tags: joomla-2.5, jquery, virtuemart

I'm actually fixing the website of a client with the next features:

- Joomla 2.5
- Virtuemart 2
- Template: Shaper iStore II
- Slider: Revolution Slider

The problem is my slider doesn't work. This text appears:
"The Current Version of jQuery:1,6,1  Please update your jQuery Version to min. 1.7 in Case you wish to use the Revolution Slider Plugin"

So, what did I do? I downloaded JQuery Easy and I updated the JQuery to the last version... It worked perfectly... but now, VM Jquery doesn't work.

- Cart pop-ups don't appear when I buy a product...
- Price doesn't change when I select the variant of a product...

If I disable JQuery Easy, it works... but slider doesn't
I have tried to change of slider and disabling some features of VM as loading some scripts files or jquery libraries, but neither...
Any idea about what should I do?

**Web page: http://www.benaventegrow.com/**

**Enabling JQuery Easy: http://gyazo.com/d6239e557bb1f75e262458117b9dd353**

Comment: Can you please either provide a link to your site or show us what errors are appearing in the console

Comment: @Lodder Check it out

Comment: I was thinking about it... If I disable JQuery Easy, my Jquery version is low, If I enable it, it doesn't and VM doesn't work correctly... Which version of JQuery supports VM 2? Higher than 1.7? Is there anyway to update it?

Comment: Does VirtueMart have an option to disable jQuery?

Comment: Yes, it does, but if i disable it, variants wont work

Comment: Have you tried disabling it then enabling jQuery Easy then checked for any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, and this happens http://gyazo.com/714b68198ae7d50bebf8999ca21d3d9d

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22215/discussion-between-antonio-and-lodder).